# iTextSharp - dynamic content with a footer, using padding

Tags: c#, .net, itext, footer

I am attempting to create documents that are highly-variable in length, and make them something that can be table-driven.  I am trying to use iTextSharp tables exclusively to create the documents, including footer verbiage.  In the code below I’m trying to pad the very last cell to the exact amount equal to the remaining space, so that my footer will be placed exactly at the bottom of the document, tight against the bottom margin.  This works fine when I try to use document margins of 1, 2, or 3 inches, but when I use 5 for example, my footer begins to wrap.  I think this may simply be a case of bad math.  Does anyone have any suggestions to correct this (outside of using Page Events)?

(*Note:  there are 2 helper methods used in creating tables and measuring the height of a paragraph, also included in addition to the main code from a button click)

(*Note:  each table has SplitLate set to false, to make the content flow from page to page evenly);  all tables have a specific width, and the width is locked

```
        //declare path for the PDF file to be created
        string strpath = @"C:\CROauto\Junk\MSE.pdf";

        //instantiate a new PDF document
        //(regular portrait format, with half-inch margins all around)
        var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER,
                               iTextSharp.text.Utilities.InchesToPoints(1f),
                               iTextSharp.text.Utilities.InchesToPoints(1f),
                               iTextSharp.text.Utilities.InchesToPoints(5f),
                               iTextSharp.text.Utilities.InchesToPoints(.5f));

        //create a PDF table
        //(2 column, with no border)
        PdfPTable mas_tbl = clsPDF.CreateTable(2, false, cell_padding_bottom: 0f, total_width: doc.PageSize.Width - doc.LeftMargin - doc.RightMargin);

        //get base font types
        BaseFont font_tb = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD).BaseFont;
        BaseFont font_t = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES).BaseFont;

        //create regular Font objects, with varying sizes
        iTextSharp.text.Font f10 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(font_t, 10);
        iTextSharp.text.Font f8 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(font_t, 8);

        //create regular Font objects, bold, with varying sizes
        iTextSharp.text.Font fb10 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(font_tb, 10);
        iTextSharp.text.Font fb8 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(font_tb, 8);

        //get image
        iTextSharp.text.Image da_img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\CROauto\Junk\img.gif");

        //scale the image to a good size
        da_img.ScaleAbsolute(iTextSharp.text.Utilities.InchesToPoints(.75f),
                             iTextSharp.text.Utilities.InchesToPoints(.75f));

        //create new PDF cell to hold image
        PdfPCell icell = new PdfPCell();

        icell.PaddingBottom = 0f;

        //make sure the "image" cell has no border
        icell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

        //add the image to the PDF cell
        icell.AddElement(da_img);

        //add the image cell to the table
        mas_tbl.AddCell(icell);

        //work with the return address
        PdfPCell ra = new PdfPCell();
        ra.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        ra.PaddingBottom = 5f;

        PdfPTable tblra = clsPDF.CreateTable(1, false);

        tblra.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        Chunk c = new Chunk("Help Me Please", fb8);

        string rtnadd = "\r\n123 iTextSharp Rd\r\nHelpMe, ST 12345\r\n\r\nstackoverflow.com";

        Phrase pra = new Phrase(rtnadd, f8);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetLeading(1f, 1.1f);
        p.Add(c);
        p.Add(pra);

        tblra.TotalWidth = clsPDF.GetLongestWidth(p) + ra.PaddingLeft + ra.PaddingRight + 2;

        ra.AddElement(p);

        tblra.AddCell(ra);

        PdfPCell dummy = new PdfPCell();
        dummy.PaddingBottom = 0f;
        dummy.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        dummy.AddElement(tblra);

        mas_tbl.AddCell(dummy);

        //create "content" table
        PdfPTable t2 = clsPDF.CreateTable(1, false, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, cell_padding_bottom: 0f);

        //create FileStream for the file
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strpath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            //get an instance of a PdfWriter, attached to the FileStream
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

            //open the document
            doc.Open();

            string tmp = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            {
                tmp += "The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog a whole bunch of times." + i.ToString();
            }

            Phrase p2 = new Phrase(tmp, f10);

            t2.AddCell(p2);

            p2 = new Phrase("Another paragraph", f10);

            t2.AddCell(p2);

            tmp = "";

            PdfPTable t3 = clsPDF.CreateTable(1, false, cell_padding_bottom: 0f);

            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                tmp += "The lazy dog didn't like that very much." + i.ToString();
            }

            t3.AddCell(new Phrase(tmp, f10));

            t2.AddCell(t3);

            t2.AddCell(new Phrase("I SURE HOPE THIS WORKED", f10));

            PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell();
            c2.PaddingBottom = 0f;
            c2.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            c2.Colspan = mas_tbl.NumberOfColumns;
            c2.AddElement(t2);

            mas_tbl.AddCell(c2);

            //work with adding a footer
            //FOOTER MSE:  ADD ENOUGH PADDING TO PUSH THE FOOTER TO THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE
            Paragraph fp = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Line 1 of footer\r\nLine 2 of footer\r\nhere's more of my footer text:\r\nthis project was SOOOO much fun\r\nand stuff", fb8));

            //get the height of the footer
            float footer_height = clsPDF.GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(fp);

            Console.WriteLine("Footer height {0}", footer_height.ToString());

            //get the total amount of "writeable" space per page
            //(taking top and bottom margins into consideration)
            float avail = doc.PageSize.Height - (doc.TopMargin + doc.BottomMargin);

            //declare a variable to assist in calculating
            //the total amount of "writeable" room remaining
            //on the last page;
            //start with with the current height of the master table
            //(will do math below to calculate just what it's using
            // on the last page)
            float mas_tbl_last_page_height = mas_tbl.TotalHeight;

            //the purpose of this loop is to start determining
            //how much writeable space is left on the last page;
            //this loop will subtract the "available" value from
            //the total height of the master table until what's
            //left is the amount of space the master table is 
            //using on the last page of the document only
            while (mas_tbl_last_page_height > avail)
            {
                mas_tbl_last_page_height -= avail;
            }

            //to truly calculate the amount of writeable space
            //remaining, subtract the amount of space that the
            //master table is utilizing on the last page of
            //the document, from the total amount of writeable
            //space per page
            float room_remaining = avail - mas_tbl_last_page_height;

            //declare variable for the padding amount
            //that will be used above the footer
            float pad_amt = 0f;

            if (room_remaining > (footer_height * 2))
            {
                //pad to push down
                pad_amt = room_remaining - (footer_height * 2);
            }
            else
            {
                //don't use a pad
                //(just let the table wrap normally)
                pad_amt = 0f;
            }

            //declare the footer cell, and set all of it's values
            PdfPCell ftcell = new PdfPCell();
            ftcell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

            //(use column span that is equal to the number of
            // columns in the master table)
            ftcell.Colspan = mas_tbl.NumberOfColumns;

            ftcell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            ftcell.PaddingTop = pad_amt;
            ftcell.PaddingBottom = 0f;
            ftcell.AddElement(fp);

            //add the footer cell to the master table
            mas_tbl.AddCell(ftcell);

            //add the master table to the document, which should contain everything
            doc.Add(mas_tbl);

            //close the document
            doc.Close();



//HELPER METHODS
internal static PdfPTable CreateTable(int column_count,
                                      bool include_border,
                                      int h_align = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                                      int v_align = Element.ALIGN_TOP,
                                      float leading_multiplier = 1.1f,
                                      float total_width = 468f,
                                      float cell_padding_bottom = 5f,
                                      float cell_padding_top = 0)
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(column_count);

    //this line will keep the inner tables, 
    //from splitting off onto a 2nd page
    //(making them only do it on wrapping)
    //*NOTE:  this needs to be tested thoroughly
    //        to make sure that rows aren't dropped!!!
    t.SplitLate = false;

    //used if you're adding paragraphs directly to table cells,
    //instead of adding new PdfPCell objects
    if (include_border == false)
    {
        t.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    }

    t.DefaultCell.PaddingLeft = 0f;

    t.DefaultCell.PaddingRight = 0f;

    t.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = cell_padding_top;

    t.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = cell_padding_bottom;

    t.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = h_align;

    t.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = h_align;

    t.TotalWidth = total_width;

    t.LockedWidth = true;

    t.DefaultCell.SetLeading(0, leading_multiplier);

    return t;
}

internal static float GetLongestWidth(Paragraph p)
{

    List<float> f = new List<float>();

    foreach (Chunk c in p.Chunks)
    {
        string[] strarray = c.Content.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
        for (int i = 0; i < strarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Chunk tc = new Chunk(strarray[i], c.Font);
            Console.WriteLine(tc.Content + ", width: {0}", tc.GetWidthPoint().ToString());
            f.Add(tc.GetWidthPoint());
        }
    }

    return f.Max();

}

internal static float GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(Paragraph p)
{

    PdfPTable t = clsPDF.CreateTable(1, false, cell_padding_bottom: 0f);

    t.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 0f;
    t.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = 0f;

    t.AddCell(p);

    return t.TotalHeight;

}
```

Comment: In my experience the rendering engine is so poor in iTextSharp that pagevents are the only real way of signalling. I would urge you to recognise iTextSharps limitations

Comment: I see it from a different angle (it's not a matter of a poor engine but of poor understanding of the design: direct content is for putting stuff at absolute positions; if you want something to be positioned absolutely, use direct content; and if it is something to put there on every page, use page events). But the result is the same as Paul's: use page events and direct content.

Comment: Using direct content would be an acceptable solution, to absolutely position my footer on the last page only.  However, with my content being a variable length, how can I tell how much room I have left on the last page, so that I can determine if I have enough room for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using absolute positioning.  I calculate the position that the footer should be in, by adding the footer height to the value of the bottom margin.  To alleviate concerns about overwriting existing content, I calculate the amount of available space remaining on the last page;  if it's not enough for my footer, I add a new page and post my content at the beginning of the next page.

```
        byte[] content;

        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader pdf_rdr = new PdfReader(strpath);

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdf_rdr, output);

            PdfContentByte pcb = stamper.GetOverContent(pdf_rdr.NumberOfPages);

            PdfPTable ftbl = clsPDF.CreateTable(1, false, cell_padding_bottom: 0f);

            Paragraph fp = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Line 1 of footer\r\nLine 2 of footer\r\nhere's more of my footer text:\r\nthis project was SOOOO much fun\r\nand stuff", fb8));

            //get the height of the footer
            float footer_height = clsPDF.GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(fp);

            Console.WriteLine("Footer height {0}", footer_height.ToString());

            //get the total amount of "writeable" space per page
            //(taking top and bottom margins into consideration)
            float avail = doc.PageSize.Height - (doc.TopMargin + doc.BottomMargin);

            //declare a variable to assist in calculating
            //the total amount of "writeable" room remaining
            //on the last page;
            //start with with the current height of the master table
            //(will do math below to calculate just what it's using
            // on the last page)
            float mas_tbl_last_page_height = mas_tbl.TotalHeight;

            mas_tbl_last_page_height = mas_tbl_last_page_height % avail;

            avail = avail - mas_tbl_last_page_height;

            Console.WriteLine(clsPDF.GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(fp).ToString());

            //float ft_top = avail - mas_tbl_last_page_height - clsPDF.GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(fp) - doc.BottomMargin;
            float ft_top = doc.BottomMargin + clsPDF.GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(fp);

            ftbl.AddCell(fp);

            if (avail < clsPDF.GetTotalHeightOfParagraph(fp))
            {
                stamper.InsertPage(pdf_rdr.NumberOfPages + 1, pdf_rdr.GetPageSize(1));
                pcb = stamper.GetOverContent(pdf_rdr.NumberOfPages);
                ft_top = doc.PageSize.Height - doc.TopMargin;
            }

            ftbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.LeftMargin, ft_top, pcb);

            // Set the flattening flag to true, as the editing is done
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;

            // close the pdf stamper
            stamper.Close();

            //close the PDF reader
            pdf_rdr.Close();

            content = output.ToArray();

        }

        //write the content to a PDF file
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(strpath))
        {
            fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
            fs.Flush();
        }
```